# How to run the performance test scripts on Load impact in different environment

Tags: performance-testing

I recently used loadimpact.com for performance testing , written a lua script and able to run in the loadimpact.com. Now how to run my lua script on different environments.I need to parameterize the environment URL , i can use csv files.But keeping csv files for different environment is not preferred.Can any one help me on this please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions.  You can use util.dns_remap() in version 3.0 (Lua scripting)

```
-- Remap loadimpact.com to IP 195.178.177.179
util.dns_remap("example.com", "195.178.177.179")

-- All requests to mysite.com will now be sent to 195.178.177.179
local response = http.request_batch({
    {"GET", "http://example.com/"}
})
```

You should consider utilizing v4.0 and k6 (k6.io) with JavaScript scripting.  When triggering your test from the command line you can pass environment variables to the test/script to test different environments.  This would require rewriting your existing scripts though. e.g.

`k6 cloud -e MY_HOSTNAME=dev.example.com script.js`

Where the following script is script.js:

```
import { check, sleep } from "k6";
import http from "k6/http";

export default function() {
    var r = http.get(`http://${__ENV.MY_HOSTNAME}/`);
    check(r, {
        "status is 200": (r) => r.status === 200
    });
    sleep(5);
}
```

This would allow you to utilize the Load Impact cloud service and solving the original problem a little more elegantly.  You can either pass a new ENV variable for your tests or if you are automating tests in a CI pipeline you can pass a new ENV.  If each build was creating it's own unique environment, this would be very handy.